# Vous ferais part ou vous ferai part ?

Tags: conjugaison, conditionnel, indicatif

Lors de la rédaction d'un mail, j'ai eu un doute à propos de l'utilisation de *"faire"*, voici la phrase en question:

> Je reste donc dans l'attente de ce dernier et vous ferais part dès lorsque que j'ai des nouvelles.

Cette dernière comporte-t-elle des fautes? Faut il dire ***vous ferais part*** ou bien ***vous ferai part*** ? Pourquoi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est le futur qu'il faut (ferai); « dès lors » est la locution habituelle dans cette construction ; « dès lorsque » ne se trouve en comparaison que [très rarement](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=d%C3%A8s+lorsque%2Cd%C3%A8s+lors&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A8s%20lorsque%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A8s%20lors%3B%2Cc0).

De plus, il faut un complément pour le verbe « faire part » ; (« je vous ferai part de son arrivée », par exemple).

Le pourquoi est qu'il n'y a aucune condition sur l'action et qu'elle se passe dans le futur.

Voici un contexte où le conditionnel serait le mode à utiliser ;

- Je reste donc dans l'attente de ce dernier  et serais très satisfait s'il arrivait avant la fin de la semaine, mais je n'y compte pas.

Cependant, on peut encore utiliser le futur, si l'on change le temps de la seconde proposition ;

- Je reste donc dans l'attente de ce dernier  et serai très satisfait s'il arrive avant la fin de la semaine, mais je n'y compte pas.